# What is the best way to cancel a socket receive request?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# you have 3 ways to try and receive TCP data on a `Socket`:

1. `Socket.Receive` is a synchronous, blocking method. It doesn't return until it succeeds, barring failure or [optionally] timeout.
2. `Socket.BeginReceive` is asynchronous, a supplied callback/delegate is called when there is data to receive, using the now-antiquated Begin/End pattern
3. `Socket.ReceiveAsync` begins an asynchronous request to receive data

However my understanding is none of these actually let you cancel the receive operation? The docs suggest `EndReceive` is used for completing a read, not something one could call to terminate the request?

You often see code like
`while(socket.Available==0 && !cancel)Sleep(50); if(!cancel)socket.Receive(...);`

But that's pretty terrible.

If I want to sit waiting for data but at some point cancel the receive, say the user hits "stop" button how can this neatly be done so I don't get a callback triggered later on when unexpected?

I had wondered about closing the socket, which would cause the Receive operation to fail, but it seems somewhat ugly. Am I thinking along the right lines or do the various API methods listed above allow a direct cancellation so I don't risk dangling async operations?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "TCP receive call/request". TCP deals with packets that go either direction, not requests and responses such as HTTP. What **exactly** are you wondering about? Do you just want to break out of a blocking `socket.Receive()` _method_ call? And what's wrong with closing the socket to do so?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with it, that's why I asked. Deliberately causing a failure to end an operation seems rather... inelegant. Like stopping my car by asking a friend to drop a tree in front of it :)

Comment: Yeah, sockets are ugly.

Comment: Ha. This is kind of why I ask - maybe it's a normal way to do things, but not intuitive. Although I find if I do this, I don't _get_ a failure but receive 0 bytes successfully from a blocking call. I was expecting `SocketException`

Comment: There is no way to cancel pending asynchronous I/O. The Windows kernel does support this (through `CancelIoEx`) but that's a relatively recent invention and not surfaced in .NET (that I know of) -- and even then it won't work for sockets. The usual approach is to assign one and only one "receive loop" to do all the communication and "cancel" by closing the socket (i.e. you're completely done). If you need an interruptable read, make it so that receive loop posts to a queue or signals an event, and wait only on *that*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - CancelIoEx is used internally by .NET for quite a time: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_PooledStream.cs,653 . From .NET, closing the socket seems the best way as it's supposed to handle edge cases. Note ServicePointManager.UseSafeSynchronousClose (not officially documented) is true by default AFAIK.

Comment: @SimonMourier: interesting! I interpreted the help page of `CancelIoEx` listing the tecnologies that supported the function as complete, that is, sockets weren't included, but apparently it does work for sockets. Doesn't change the fact that .NET doesn't directly expose this, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - yep. In fact they do pretty advanced stuff (pooling, etc.) which shields the average .NET developer (i.e: me) from socket suckiness.

Comment: @Mr.Boy i know what you want and i have done it before. but there are a lot of circumstances that should be considered. in order to answer it i have to post several answers for several conditions. you need to focus on a specific circumstance and exactly say what actually you want.

Comment: @Mr.Boy this:'If I want to sit waiting for data but at some point cancel the receive, say the user hits "stop" button how can this neatly be done so I don't get a callback triggered later on when unexpected?' explains your wish but not your goal. because , your statement can be Interpret differently .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no known way to cancel it *(AFAIK)*

One thing you can do it set the `Socket.Blocking = false`. The receive will return immediately when there is no data. This way it will not *hang*.

You should check the [Socket.Blocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking?view=netframework-4.8) property.

I advise you to use the `BeginReceive(IList<ArraySegment<Byte>>, SocketFlags, SocketError, AsyncCallback, Object)` overload to prevent it throwing exceptions.

Check the SocketError on "Would Block", meaning "there is not data". So you can try again.

---

Didn't tested it but ->

A nice idea is using the non-async version [Receive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Receive_System_Collections_Generic_IList_System_ArraySegment_System_Byte___System_Net_Sockets_SocketFlags_System_Net_Sockets_SocketError__) to receive 0 bytes *(use a static byte[] emptyBuffer = new byte[0])* , and if the sockerError returns with a 'would block', you can have a short delay and retry it. When it doesn't return a socketError there is probably data. So you can start an async version.

Comment: A `Receive` call with a zero-byte buffer will always fail, because there would be no way to communicate success (a return value of 0 indicates a gracefully closed connection, not that no bytes were read). For that you can use `Socket.Available`. Not that I recommend anyone use that, or non-blocking sockets in general for that matter.

Comment: I was not aware of `Socket.Blocking` that's quite useful to know since even the `ReceiveAsync` method doesn't IIRC allow cancellation

Comment: @JeroenMostert The result is zero bytes, but you have to check the errorCode before you check the received bytes. `int zeroBytes = _socket.Receive(new byte[0], 0, 0, SocketFlags.None, out var errorCode);`  and `if (errorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock) {   // wait and retry }`  It will not be optimal, because what delay should be specified to retry. It won't be more optimal than using blocking.

Comment: But still in 2020 to cancel the `BeginReceive` by closing the socket... Oef...

Comment: Still in 2021 cancelling the `BeginReceive` by closing the socket. Why has nobody figured this out? We can send pictures from Mars to Earth but we can't cancel a UDP receive if we don't get the data in time.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get a `NetworkStream` from the socket being read and use it's `ReadTimeout` property, for example:

```
// Get stream from socket:
using NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);

// Set timeout:
stream.ReadTimeout = 10 * 1000; // 10 sec
var buffer = new List<byte>();

try
{
    do
    {
        buffer.Add((byte) stream.ReadByte());
    }
    while (stream.DataAvailable);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    // Timeout
}

return buffer.ToArray();
```